# How do you scroll to the bottom of a UICollectionView?

Tags: swift, firebase, uicollectionview, firebase-realtime-database

So my current code will not scroll the list at all, regardless of the number returned by messageCount. This is located in viewDidLoad() and the data is populated by Firebase. What it causing this?

**Current Code:**

```
    self.messages.removeAll()
    collectionView?.reloadData()
    refHandle = self.ref.child("messages").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
        self.messages.append(snapshot)
        self.collectionView?.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: self.messages.count - 1, inSection: 0)])
    })

    refHandle = ref.child("messages").observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        let messageCount = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
        print(messageCount) //temp
        self.collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: messageCount - 1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
    })
```

Comment: Try calling it on the main thread

Answer (score 1):

try this

```

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { 
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                self.scrollToBottom()
            })
```

```
inside the observe closure

and this is the scroll to bottom func

```

```
func scrollToBottom() {
        let section = (collectionView?.numberOfSections)! - 1
        let lastItemIndex = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: section)
        self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: lastItemIndex, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
```

```